# URL Encoding/Decoding - Django Internet Explorer

Tags: html, django, forms, internet-explorer, urlencode

How does django automatically encode and decode form data? Say, I have the following form.

```
 <form method="POST" action="MY_SERVER_URL">
    <p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input id="id_name" type="text" name="name"/></p>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
 </form>
```

When I try to post this form with name value as say "This is name value" to my Server and when I am using Chrome or Firefox or Safari, the request.POST['name'] in my view gives me string correctly but on Internet Explorer it gives me "This+is+name+value" and I have to run a urllib.unquote_plus() on it to get the appropriate value (This is name value, that is!).

In short, all form data from Internet Explorer seem to not have been decoded or encoded in a different format. (Which one?) I have searched for this extensively on stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything that is of help. Learned opinions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an `enctype` property to the form. IE should default to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but you never know with IE. I know an enctype of text/plain would convert spaces to +.

Try:

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

or use: `multiplart/form-data` if your form needs to support file fields.

Comment: Thanks. But, if I remember correctly, even application/x-www-form-urlencoded also encodes spaces to "+" symbols, and special characters are converted to ASCII HEX values. (which was happening alright)

The problem here is with Firefox/Chrome, the framework I am using(Django) seems to be automatically decoding the encoded form data on form submits but with IE, it doesn't seem to be doing the same. If I have to check for the UserAgent everytime and decode the data, even the non IE users will have to go through that check and that's an extra call. I must do some more reading I guess.

Comment: I've actually never seen the behavior you're experiencing with a form in Django, and I've been using it since 0.96. Would you mind posting your model/view code so we can get the whole picture?

Comment: Sorry formatting is messed up. I'm on mobile. Will attach the link in a short while.